# Comparing Two Almost the Same Audio File(.MP3)

Tags: python, audio, compare

I have a lot of these small .mp3 files, and what I want to get here is to check if two audio speaks the same alphabet.

For example:

```
if audio_is_same("file1.mp3", "file2.mp3"):
    print("Same")
else:
    print("Different")
```

And here are some
[Audio Samples](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IuHPwAlssaF_ZX5vGPIxktr5IMbstNtE?usp=sharing) (Some folders are empty.)

Since these audio are almost the same, I think it is possible to do it with a simple way?

Would training a audio recognition module simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Audio files are just binary when you open them, so you can just compare the files after reading them in.

```
def compare_audio(file1, file2):

    is_same = open(“file1”, "rb").read() == open(“file2”, "rb").read() 
    if is_same:
        print('Same')
    else:
        print('Different')
```

If you have large files, compare in chunks as mentioned in the below link.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-compare-two-binary-files-in-Python

If you want to get some sort of similarity between the two you can use built in similarity function or some kind of model

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

threshold = 0.8

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def compare_audio(file1, file2):

    file1 = open(“file1”, "rb").read()
    file2 = open(“file2”, "rb").read()
 
    sim_ratio = similar(file1, file2)
    
    if sim_ratio > threshold:
        print('Same')
    else:
        print('Different')
```

You would need to decide what an appropriate threshold is.

Comment: Just realized you are asking if the language is the same of the files? That would probably need a model.

Comment: That would not work because these files are just "sound" the same, instead of "exact" the same.

Comment: I think the binary should still be similar, but this would take some kind of model to compare the binary between the two files. Then you would need to get a similarity score. I've updated my answer for something that might work.

Comment: If that simple library doesn't work, you might need to do some more complicated modeling.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. sim_ratio has no connection between the sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically what differences are you looking for, but below there's a code to get a number from 0 to 100 for the similarity from two audio files using python, it works by generating fingerprints from audio files and comparing them based out of them using cross correlation

It requires [Chromaprint](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint) and [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) installed, also it doesn't work for short audio files, if this is a problem, you can always reduce the speed of the audio like in this [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), be aware this is going to add a little noise.

```py
# correlation.py
import subprocess
import numpy
# seconds to sample audio file for
sample_time = 500# number of points to scan cross correlation over
span = 150# step size (in points) of cross correlation
step = 1# minimum number of points that must overlap in cross correlation
# exception is raised if this cannot be met
min_overlap = 20# report match when cross correlation has a peak exceeding threshold
threshold = 0.5
# calculate fingerprint
def calculate_fingerprints(filename):
    fpcalc_out = subprocess.getoutput('fpcalc -raw -length %i %s' % (sample_time, filename))
    fingerprint_index = fpcalc_out.find('FINGERPRINT=') + 12
    # convert fingerprint to list of integers
    fingerprints = list(map(int, fpcalc_out[fingerprint_index:].split(',')))      
    return fingerprints  
    # returns correlation between lists
def correlation(listx, listy):
    if len(listx) == 0 or len(listy) == 0:
        # Error checking in main program should prevent us from ever being
        # able to get here.     
        raise Exception('Empty lists cannot be correlated.')    
    if len(listx) > len(listy):     
        listx = listx[:len(listy)]  
    elif len(listx) < len(listy):       
        listy = listy[:len(listx)]      

    covariance = 0  
    for i in range(len(listx)):     
        covariance += 32 - bin(listx[i] ^ listy[i]).count("1")  
    covariance = covariance / float(len(listx))     
    return covariance/32  
    # return cross correlation, with listy offset from listx
def cross_correlation(listx, listy, offset):    
    if offset > 0:      
        listx = listx[offset:]      
        listy = listy[:len(listx)]  
    elif offset < 0:        
        offset = -offset        
        listy = listy[offset:]      
        listx = listx[:len(listy)]  
    if min(len(listx), len(listy)) < min_overlap:       
    # Error checking in main program should prevent us from ever being      
    # able to get here.     
        return   
    #raise Exception('Overlap too small: %i' % min(len(listx), len(listy))) 
    return correlation(listx, listy)  
    # cross correlate listx and listy with offsets from -span to span
def compare(listx, listy, span, step):  
    if span > min(len(listx), len(listy)):      
    # Error checking in main program should prevent us from ever being      
    # able to get here.     
        raise Exception('span >= sample size: %i >= %i\n' % (span, min(len(listx), len(listy))) + 'Reduce span, reduce crop or increase sample_time.')

    corr_xy = []    
    for offset in numpy.arange(-span, span + 1, step):      
        corr_xy.append(cross_correlation(listx, listy, offset)) 
    return corr_xy  
    # return index of maximum value in list
def max_index(listx):   
    max_index = 0   
    max_value = listx[0]    
    for i, value in enumerate(listx):       
        if value > max_value:           
            max_value = value           
            max_index = i   
    return max_index  

def get_max_corr(corr, source, target): 
    max_corr_index = max_index(corr)    
    max_corr_offset = -span + max_corr_index * step 
    print("max_corr_index = ", max_corr_index, "max_corr_offset = ", max_corr_offset)
    # report matches    
    if corr[max_corr_index] > threshold:        
        print(('%s and %s match with correlation of %.4f at offset %i' % (source, target, corr[max_corr_index], max_corr_offset))) 

def correlate(source, target):  
    fingerprint_source = calculate_fingerprints(source) 
    fingerprint_target = calculate_fingerprints(target)     
    corr = compare(fingerprint_source, fingerprint_target, span, step)  
    max_corr_offset = get_max_corr(corr, source, target)  

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    correlate(SOURCE_FILE, TARGET_FILE)
```

Code converted into python 3 from: https://shivama205.medium.com/audio-signals-comparison-23e431ed2207